# PHP: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, error-handling

Here is the line that the error is coming from...

```
If (password_verify($password, $user['password'])){}
```

Here is what's inside this of statement...

```
    $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id']; 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username']; 
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email']; 
    $_SESSION['verified'] = $user['verified']; 
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Success!"; 
    $_SESSION['alert-class'] = "alert-success"; 
    header ('location: verification.php'); 
    exit(); 
} else { 
    $errors['login_fail'] = "Incorrect Username or Password"; 
}
```

Comment: The error occurs whenever i attempt to enter both a username and password combination that does not exist in the database.

Comment: I assume you did `$user = some_fetch();` or something which is returning null because no rows in DB.  Show more code.

Comment: I did $user = $result->fetch_assoc();

Comment: And what's your question? What have you tried to debug this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you've managed to load the user from DB. It looks like the function that is loading data from DB returns `null` when the user is not found.

You can change your condition to something like this:

```php
if(!empty($user) && password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
  // ... log in user
} else {
  // ... do something when password or user doesn't match
}
```

Comment: I apologize, first time using this platform.